# issue with equal space between <li> tags with a nested <a> and <img> tags

Tags: html, css

I try to do a nice list with `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. My issue is that I would like to have equal space between `<li>`. In my case, one of the `<li>` contains a `<a>` tag followed by a `<img>` logo tag itself included in a `<a>` tag.

Here is the code :

```
<ul>
<li><a class="bottom_link" href="test1">Image for test 1</a></li>
<br>
<li><a class="bottom_link" href="test2">Image for test 2 using yunka</a></li>
<br>
    <li class="withlogo"><a class="bottom_link" href="test3">Compression and Decompression using test 3</a> <a class="bottom_link" href="test3.pdf"><img class="logo" width="40" height="40" src="pdf-logo.gif"></a></li>
 <br>
        <li><a class="bottom_link" href="test2">Image for test 4 using polif</a></li>
    </ul>
```

You can check the result on : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yisi99/abm4r49y/1/)

As you can see, the last `<li>` text is not aligned with the bullet.

I managed in solving this first problem (I can't reproduce it on jsfiddle) but it remains one principal issue :

**How to keep an equal space between all the `<li>` tags (even with the third one which has a nested `<img>` tag (pdf logo)) ?**

I tried to use :

```
  line-height: auto;
  height: auto;
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi now as like this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/abm4r49y/8/

Comment: line-height: auto, height: auto is not a solution. What you need to do is calculate the height of each li after image rendered successfully and apply it to other <li>s through javascript.

Comment: Your height and line-height idea is great – it's just that `auto` is not big enough to accommodate the image. Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abm4r49y/17/) that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `vertical-align` work, use`display:inline-block` instead of `block`.
If you will set line-height for a equal to image height, spaces will be equal.

```
a.bottom_link:active,a.bottom_link:visited,a.bottom_link:link{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
color: #004478;  
             line-height: 40px;
height: auto; 
}

li { 
display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
                 padding-left: 17px;
                 background-image: url(http://kawito.dyndns-at-home.com/bullet1.png);
                 background-repeat: no-repeat;
                 background-position: left center ;              
                 vertical-align: middle;

}


img.logo  {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abm4r49y/16/

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but the line-height counts towards all elements. One of the elements is the image in your background in li part. Try to delete image or import it in  tag and it will start depend its height on line-height.

But you need to give him right height.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi now define your `li` `line-height`

```
li{line-height:40px;}
```

and this `li.withlogo` **remove** `line-height` and `height`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/abm4r49y/12/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can put a **maximum line height** in px for all the li Elements,

afterwards for img.logo set **height: 100%** , and **width: auto**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is li  s and ul s are displaying  inline. You must set display=block to li selector